# problem with python binance api order_market_buy and order_market_sell

Tags: python, api, binance

I am trying to use order_market_buy and order_market_sell to buy/sell,
taking BTCUSDT for example, when buying, I want to use all my usdt, when selling, I want to sell all the BTC.

I use

```
order_buy = Client.order_market_buy(symbol='BTCUSDT', quoteOrderQty=my_USDT_position)
order_sell = Client.order_market_sell(symbol='BTCUSDT', quoteOrderQty=my_BTC_position)
```

it's not working and pop"missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"

Please help me with the problem, thanks!

Comment: hi there.  please add the rest of the code to put the above into context and replicate the problem.   generally like this:   https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You can get you current balance of a specific asset then passes it as a parameter in the order_market_buy method.

Example:

```
usdtBalance = client.get_asset_balance(asset='USDT').get('free')
btcBalance = client.get_asset_balance(asset='BTC').get('free')

order_buy = Client.order_market_buy(symbol='BTCUSDT', quantity=usdtBalance)

order_sell = Client.order_market_sell(symbol='BTCUSDT', quantity=btcBalance)
```

Comment: for your order_buy and order_sell method, do I need to provide "quantity" ? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, the correct parameter is quantity (required).  quoteOrderQty is used to specify how much you want to buy/sell of a given asset.

Comment: so if I want to use order_buy to spend all my usdt to buy btc, and use order_sell to dump all my btc, what the code should be? Thank you. btw, I use order_buy = client.order_market_buy(symbol='BTCUSDT', quoteOrderQty=usdtBalance) it works without quantity. but order_sell is not working

Comment: **Note**: param `quantity` requires the *type* input to be `decimal` (i.e. `float`), meaning that the correct input in `Client.order_market_buy(symbol='BTCUSDT', quantity=usdtBalance)` should be `Client.order_market_buy(symbol='BTCUSDT', quantity=float(usdtBalance))`. This is a correct approach since `client.get_asset_balance(asset='USDT').get('free')` returns a `str` obj and not a `float` obj by default at this time.

Answer (score 0):

From their documentation:
https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/binance.html?highlight=order_market_buy#binance.client.Client.order_market_buy

It seems that you did not input a quantity argument in the function call of order_market_buy and order_market_sell, that is why you are getting an error. quantity and symbol are a required parameter of these functions.

So I think to solve the "missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'" error you should do:

```
order_buy = Client.order_market_buy(symbol='BTCUSDT', quantity=<your quantity>, quoteOrderQty=my_USDT_position)
order_sell = Client.order_market_sell(symbol='BTCUSDT', quantity=<your quantity>, quoteOrderQty=my_BTC_position)
```

Comment: Just a little note, I am not 100% sure this will solve the error, because I haven't tested the code. I am just basing it on their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also try something like this?

```
usdtBalance = Client.get_asset_balance(asset='USDT').get('free') 

#use param quoteOrderQty instead of param quantity when buying
order_buy = Client.order_market_buy(symbol='BTCUSDT', quoteOrderQty=usdtBalance)

##Some time later##

btcBalance = Client.get_asset_balance(asset='BTC').get('free')

#use param quantity instead of param quoteOrderQty when selling
order_sell = Client.order_market_sell(symbol='BTCUSDT', quantity=btcBalance)
```

Based on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71589830/problem-with-python-binance-api-order-market-buy-and-order-market-sell#comment126549921_71594630), it seems that `Client.order_market_buy(symbol='BTCUSDT', quoteOrderQty=usdtBalance)` **worked for buying**, but `Client.order_market_sell(symbol='BTCUSDT', quantity=btcBalance)` **did NOT for selling**.

I tend to think it's because the information you stored in `btcBalance` was prior to the purchase you made right after initializing `btcBalance`, it would make sense since that way you would have stored `0.00` or just **"[Dust](https://www.binance.com/en/support/faq/360003012371/)"** which is *a very low amount of the base asset* that can't be used for trading on Binance but instead for just converting to **BNB**.

In this [guide](https://sammchardy.github.io/binance-order-filters/), there's an example using the `Testnet Binance Vision`, although it illustrates very well how to set a `Market Sell Order` with `Python Binance` package:

```
from binance.exceptions import BinanceAPIException

api_key = '<testnet api_key>'
api_secret = '<testnet api_secret>'

async def main():

    quantity = '0.000001'
    client = await AsyncClient.create(api_key=api_key, api_secret=api_secret, testnet=True)

    try:
        market_res = await client.order_market_sell(symbol='BTCUSDT', quantity=quantity)
    except BinanceAPIException as e:
        print(e)
    else:
        print(json.dumps(market_res, indent=2))

    await client.close_connection()
```

It even says that if the value stored in `quantity` is not greater than the `MIN_NOTIONAL` value, you will get the following error:

> `APIError(code=-1013): Filter failure: MIN_NOTIONAL`

I recommend you to check it out, it may help you better when dealing with this topic.

Answer (score 0):

When trading a pair (BTC and USDT) you can either specify the BTC amount you want to buy/sell in the `quantity` parameter, or the USDT you want to buy/sell in the `quoteOrderQty` parameter.

```
btc_balance = client.get_asset_balance(asset='BTC')
btc_balance = btc_balance['free']

usdt_balance = client.get_asset_balance(asset='USDT')
usdt_balance = usdt_balance['free']

# Sell BTC
sell_order = client.order_market_sell(
                 symbol='BTCUSDT', 
                 quantity=btc_balance
             )

# Buy BTC
buy_order = client.order_market_buy(
                 symbol='BTCUSDT', 
                 quoteOrderQty = usdt_balance
            )
```